# Is it possible to temporarily remove margin from iTerm2 window?

Tags: iterm, vi

I just wondering whether its possible to remove the left, right and top margin (or just all margin) temporarily in iTerm2 windows. My goal was to make the vim-airline looks better in iTerm2 by removing those margin. Here's the screenshot of the margin I want to remove..

[image: How to remove those margin?]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to fork and build iterm yourself. Here's a project where somebody did that: https://github.com/jaredculp/iterm2-borderless-padding